# How to check if functions are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I have 2 functions:

$$\tag{1} f_1(x) = \cos x - 2x$$
$$\tag{2} f_2(x) = x^2 \sin x$$

Where $f_1,f_2:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$

And I need to check whether they are linearly dependent or not.

*NOTE: I didn't learn about Wronskian

### ---

So I can take 2 scalars in R, $a_1,a_2 \in \Bbb R$ and check the solutions for:
$$a_1(\cos x - 2x) + a_2(x^2 \sin x) = 0$$
So I think I can take like: $a_1 = -\frac{x^2 \sin x}{\cos x -2x}, a_2 = 1, x = \pi \Rightarrow a_1 = 0$.

But it seems that i could even take: $a_1 = 0, a_2 = 1, x=\pi$ and it would hold.

So the scalars are non zero, the linear combination is zero, so the functions are linear dependent, did i made any mistake? (It seems to me a little bit weird)

Is it ok that I chose a specific $x$ for the solution or I somehow should show it $\forall x \in \Bbb R?$

if $\forall x$, I could still take: $a_1 = -\frac{x^2 \sin x}{\cos x -2x}, a_2 = 1$ and it would hold, no?

Comment: Function aren't single value, so firstly (as you asked later), you should show it for all $x \in \mathbb R$. But, then you cannot take any $a_1,a_2$ dependent on $x$, since $x$ is arbitrary, not fixed.

Comment: You're right until you choose a particular value for $x$ - it has to hold, as you ask later, for all $x$, i.e., identically 0.

Comment: There needs to be scalars for which that holds, for *all* values of the independent variable.

Comment: So i need to find $a_1,a_2 \in \Bbb R$ that are not dependent on $x$ but are fixed values?

Comment: Yes, $x$ has nothing to do with the function itself. In this context $af(x) + bg(x)=0$ really means $(af+bg)(x)=0$, i.e. $af+bg \equiv 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: take different values of $x$ (for example $x=\pi, x={\pi\over 2}$) in the equation to show that $a_1=a_2=0$.

For $x=\pi, a_1(-1-2\pi)=0$ implies $a_1=0$, $x={\pi\over 2}$ implies that $a_2=0$

Comment: you already have $a_1=0$ from $x=\pi$.

Comment: You are right, thank you

Comment: That means that in order for functions to be linear dependent they must be a scalar multiplication of each other $\forall x \in D$, D - domain?

Comment: yes, it means that

Answer (score 1):

This has to be true for all $x$. You can start with $x=0$ which forces $a_1=0$. Then you can choose say $x=\pi/2$ which forces $a_2=0$. Therefore they are independent.

Comment: Thank you for the help, its like the other guy said if i understood well